# Enable/disable this.props.children inside Child component based on item clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following parent/child components:

Parent:

```
handleClick = (e) => {
   console.log(e.target)
}

render () {
  <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
    {this.props.children}
  </div>
}
```

Child:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
       <div>More content here</div>
       <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Checkbox</input>
       <div>{this.props.children}</div> 
    </div> 
  )
}
```

Render:

```
<Parent>
   <div>
     <div>I am a checkbox 
       <Child>
         <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
       </Child>
     </div>
     <div>I am checkbox 2 <Child /></div>
   </div>
</Parent>
```

I want a way to enable/disable the Child's `this.props.children` based on the item clicked. Clicking away should also disable the item. Please note that Child's `this.props.children` is open to hold anything.. radio button, checkbox, dropdown etc. There's no way of knowing what it will hold prior to declaring it.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: One way is to pass the state from the Parent Component as props to the Child Component

Comment: apologies. i've updated my question to be more clear. Child now has a `this.props.children` and I want a way to disable/enable based on the Child clicked.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your situation correctly, then you want a click on the `<div>` in your **Parent** component to determine whether the **Child** component’s children render or not.

In this case, the **function as child** pattern might be of help.

First, you can set a flag in your **Parent** component’s state and toggle it when the `<div>` is clicked.

You can then render the children as a function and pass along the flag:

```
// Parent
// ...

state = { flag: false }

handleClick = () => {
  this.setState({ flag: !this.state.flag })
}

render () {
  <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
    {this.props.children(this.state.flag)}
  </div>
}

// ...
```

You can then use a function as the **Parent** component’s child to access the flag and pass it along to the **Child** component:

```
// Render
// ...

<Parent>
  {(flag) =>
    <div>
      <div>I am a checkbox 
        <Child show={flag}>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
        </Child>
      </div>
      <div>I am checkbox 2 <Child /></div>
    </div>
  }
</Parent>

// ...
```

Now you can use the **show** prop in your **Child** component to conditionally render it’s children:

```
// Child
// ...

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>More content here</div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Checkbox</input>
      <div>{this.props.show && this.props.children}</div> 
    </div> 
  )
}

// ...
```

Hopefully this is of help.